# ¿Cómo usar bootstrap en un PDF con dompdf?

Tags: php, bootstrap, dompdf

Estoy tratando de generar un reporte con información de una base de datos, y puedo mostrar toda la info de manera correcta en mi HTML con bootstrap. El problema viene cuando hago el render de mi PDF, ahí deja de funcionar bootstrap.

```
<?php 
//este es mi HTML:
ob_start(); 
?>

<!-- Todo el html va aquí <link></link> para cargar bootstrap -->


<?php $html = ob_get_clean() ?>
```

Después, en otro archivo (que es el que uso para crear el PDF), hago esto:

```
<?php


require_once 'ruta/a/dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();

include "firstFileWithHtml.php";
$options = $dompdf->getOptions();
$options->set(array('isRemoteEnabled' => true));
$dompdf->setOptions($options);

$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper("letter");

$dompdf->render();

$dompdf->stream("archivo_pdf", array("Attachment" =>false));


<?
```

Y aquí se genera la vista del PDF, solo que deja de funcionar el bootstrap.
Hay alguna opción que me falta? algún método de $dompdf que no esté configurando?

intenté descargando bootstrap a mi proyecto, intenté con el CDN, intenté con diferentes versiones (4.3.1, 5.0.2, 5.3.0), pero de momento nada me ha funcionado.

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero creo que no puedes usar directamente ninguna referencia... Usualmente toca escribir el css manual para darle diseños a los pdf

Comment: ya lo pude solucionar! jajaja olvidé escribir la respuesta, deja la agrego

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontré la manera de solucionarlo.

Resulta que si usas rutas relativas como:

```
../user/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

La librería de DOMPDF no puede leer (o encontrar) el archivo. Así que lo que hice fue cambiar la etiqueta del link al style.

lo tenía así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../user/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

y tiene que ser así:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/PROJECT/user/bootstrap-5.0.2-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Y con eso funciona correctamente.

Solo un detalle a aclarar: bootstrap y dompdf no están realmente pensados para trabajar juntos, así que hay muchas cosas que no funcionan como deberían. como comenté en la pregunta, hice pruebas con muchas versiones, y la que parece funcionar mejor es la versión 3.3.7

Espero que esta info le ayude a alguien!:)